# Switch in Java is looping

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

My switch statement just keeps looping.  It should print the option you choose and then reprint the menu.  Please help!
Here is my code:

```
menu ="\n\t1  Create Account" + 
            "\n\t2  Check balance" +
            "\n\t3  Withdraw" +
            "\n\t1  Deposit" + 
            "\n\t2  Get account ID" +
            "\n\t3  Set ID" +
            "\n\t1  Display Account Info" +

            "\n\t0  Quit\n\n\n";

    System.out.println(menu);
    System.out.println("\tEnter your selection:  ");
    option = scan.nextInt();

while (option != 0) {

            switch (option) {

            case 1: //  Enter and Validate SSN
                        System.out.print("option 1");
                        break;

            case 2:     //Enter and Validate Passwords
                        System.out.print("option 2");
                        break;

            case 3:     //Enter,Verify, and Translate a Phone keypad Number
                        System.out.print("option 3");
                        break;

            case 4: //  Enter and Validate SSN
                        System.out.print("option 4");
                        break;

            case 5:     //Enter and Validate Passwords
                        System.out.print("option 5");
                        break;

            case 6:     //Enter,Verify, and Translate a Phone keypad Number
                        System.out.print("option 6");
                        break;

            case 7:     //Enter,Verify, and Translate a Phone keypad Number
                        System.out.print("option 7");
                        break;

            default: outputString = "\nInvalid Selection\n";
                        System.out.println(outputString);
                        break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the loop in the first place? Wouldn't an `if` statement suffice? If you want to reprint the menu, the loop wouldn't do that right now; maybe the loop should contain that block as well.

Comment: no, it needs to keep printing the menu after you enter your choice. 0 quits it

Comment: And that's what I meant when I said the loop wouldn't do that. Your loop body only prints the option until it is 0, and there is nothing in the body to set it to 0. You need a `do...while` loop, with the printing logic as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's your `while` loop that is doing the looping.   And you are never changing the value of `option` within the body of the loop, so of course it runs continuously.

Presumably, you want to move the line:

```
option = scan.nextInt();
```

To the first line of the loop:

```
while (option != 0) {
    option = scan.nextInt();
    ... 
}
```

Comment: I need it to print the menu again after your choice. It just keeps printing the option you press right now.

Comment: @Josh, I'm not following you.  If you take my suggestion, it will print out the option you just typed.  Isn't that what you want?  If you want to see the menu *each* time, move that stuff into the body of the loop too.

Comment: Wow ok thank you.  I just ended up putting it at the end of the loop to recall.  What you said will do the same thing only simpler.  Thank you!

Comment: And he needs a case for `0` for it to be pretty (right now it's going to fall through to `default` and say there's an error before breaking out of the loop)

Answer (score 2):

Option is never changing in the while loop you have -- resulting in an endless loop if you type in anything that's not `0`

Answer (score 1):

A do while loop would require less code:

```
menu ="\n\t1  Create Account" + 
        "\n\t2  Check balance" +
        "\n\t3  Withdraw" +
        "\n\t1  Deposit" + 
        "\n\t2  Get account ID" +
        "\n\t3  Set ID" +
        "\n\t1  Display Account Info" +

        "\n\t0  Quit\n\n\n";

do {
  System.out.println(menu);
  System.out.println("\tEnter your selection:  ");
  option = scan.nextInt();
  switch (option) {

    case 1: //  Enter and Validate SSN
    System.out.print("option 1");
    break;

    case 2:     //Enter and Validate Passwords
    System.out.print("option 2");
    break;

    case 3:     //Enter,Verify, and Translate a Phone keypad Number
    System.out.print("option 3");
    break;

    case 4: //  Enter and Validate SSN
    System.out.print("option 4");
    break;

    case 5:     //Enter and Validate Passwords
    System.out.print("option 5");
    break;

    case 6:     //Enter,Verify, and Translate a Phone keypad Number
    System.out.print("option 6");
    break;

    case 7:     //Enter,Verify, and Translate a Phone keypad Number
    System.out.print("option 7");
    break;

    default: outputString = "\nInvalid Selection\n";
    System.out.println(outputString);
    break;

  } while (option != 0)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code keeps on looping because value of `option` never changes when you are in the loop. You need to write your logic differently. Btw, `switch` does not loop, `while` does the looping.